# Twilio MMS hitting my URL

Tags: twilio, bit.ly

We just started sending MMS from a rails app with Twilio. This MMS contains a short url that allows our client's customer's to one-click activate an offer. What I'm seeing though, is, that just the sending of the MMS seems to activate the offer. Am I 1) completely losing my mind, or 2) is this hitting that URL when it's sending the message?

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: Yes, and I'm seeing a GET for that URL basically as soon as it's sent. I guess I'm wondering why, I'm theorizing that something (Twilio, or MMS generally) is testing the links to see if they work and if not, converting to SMS? I could see that with my image, but seems odd it would hit the short url.

Comment: Can you find the 'user agent', 'ip address' , more about the get request?

Comment: It was actually bit.ly that was doing it. The URL shorteners apparently make sure they can hit the URL before shortening them, I tested it with the google one as well. Closing.

Comment: Bit.ly tends to hit the URL to try to generate a thumbnail image of the site too.

Comment: @BrotherShamus that is good to know, they probably harvest some data about too, build your own then, google 'base 62 encoding'.